# Is it possible to format individual cells in a .tsv file before opening with excel? (via python?)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, dataframe

this is my first question. I'm trying my best to make it as understandable as possible.

My Problem:
I'm writing a python program which reads an excel(.xlsm) file (~500 rows, 40 columns) and converts it via pandas into a pandas dataframe. My program then proceeds to edit the data, generate an output dataframe and write it to a .tsv file. This .tsv now consists of those 500 datapoints as rows and 7 columns with generated data by the program.

In the next step, the .tsv file will be opened in Excel, because we need to fill in the last 1 or 2 columns manually, which cannot be done by my program.

To achieve this, someone needs to process the content in the 2nd column, and deduce the content which needs to be written to those last 1 or 2 columns. The cells in the 2nd column that need to be read manually look something like this:
[Unformated Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SGTK.png)

To make it easier to read for the human, I would like to somehow format the cells in the 2nd column BEFORE you open the .tsv via excel to fill in the gaps, so that it looks something like this: [Formated Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYiwG.png)

I hope you understand my problem. Is there any way to format the whole column of 500 Cells (state of image 1 -> state of image 2) somehow in the .tsv before opening it in excel?

Answer (score 0):

TSV files cannot be formatted like that. You need to convert your TSV to Excel (XLS, for example), format it and then open it.

Comment: The problem is that we need the file to be a .tsv to further work with the data after all columns are filled in. That would be another step in the process chain.

Comment: Yes, you can do .xlsm -> pandas -> .xls -> .tsv

Comment: let me get that, you mean i export a xlsm out of my program, format all cells via python to xls, and then just export it as .tsv?

Comment: yes :) since tsv files cannot be formatted, this is basically your only option, if you want to get additional data in Excel.